# Suppose that A and B are bounded subsets of $R$ such that $a\leq b$ for any $a \in A$ ,$b \in B$

Tags: real-analysis

Then, prove $\sup(A）\leq \inf(B)$;

$\sup(A) = \inf(B)$ if and only if , given any $\epsilon >0$, there are $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $(b-a) < \epsilon$.

my attempt:

$a \leq \sup(A)$, and $\inf(B) \leq b$. How do i know $\sup(A) \leq \inf(B)$？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of infimum, $c \le \inf(B)$ for any $c$ that is a lower bound for $B$. In particular, $a \le \inf(B)$ for all $a \in A$.

Now by definition of supremum $\sup(A) \le d$ for any $d$ that is an upper bound for $A$. In particular, $\sup(A) \le \inf(B)$ since $a \le \inf(B)$ for all $a \in A$ means that $\inf(B)$ is an upper bound for $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\sup A> \sup B$ and

put $\epsilon=\sup A - \sup B$

by definition of $\sup A$,

$$\exists a\in A \;\;:\;\; \sup A-\epsilon <a\leq \sup A$$

$$\implies \exists a\in A\;\;:\; a>\sup B$$

$\implies \exists a\in A: \;\forall b\in B\; \;b\leq \sup B < a$

which is in contradiction with hypotheses.